# combing queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select sum(a.perdblnc), a.actindx
from [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] b
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10111] a
on b.actindx = a.actindx
where b.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by a.actindx

Return:
42378.15000 41
54072.64000 42
31698.21000 43
75552.65000 44

select sum(a.perdblnc), a.actindx
from [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] b
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10110] a
on b.actindx = a.actindx
where b.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by a.actindx

Retuns:
28711.94000 41
53781.08000 42
26281.17000 43
69345.59000 44
```

I need to combine it so that it returns the sum or both query.  The final result should be:

```
57423.88    41
107562.16   42
52562.34    43
138691.18   44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sum the union...

```
select sum(u.t), u.actindx
from (

select sum(a.perdblnc) as t, a.actindx
from [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] b
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10111] a
on b.actindx = a.actindx
where b.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by a.actindx

union all

select sum(a.perdblnc), a.actindx
from [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] b
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10110] a
on b.actindx = a.actindx
where b.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by a.actindx

) u
group by u.actindx
```

The `union all` is required for that rare case there are duplicate sums in those 2 GL tables.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're only summing one column, you could use subqueries like:

```
select  act.actindx
,       (select sum(a.perdblnc) from [CASH].[dbo].[GL10110] a 
         where a.actindx = act.actindx) +
        (select sum(a.perdblnc) from [CASH].[dbo].[GL10111] b
         where b.actindx = act.actindx)
from    [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] act
where   act.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by 
        act.actindx
```

If you'd need more columns, you'd usually go with another form of subquery, like:

```
select  act.actindx
,       sub_a.total + sub_b.total
from    [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] act
left join
        (
        select  a.actindx
        ,       sum(a.perdblnc) as total
        from    [CASH].[dbo].[GL10110] a 
        group by
                a.actindx
        ) sub_a
on      a.actindx = act.actindx
left join
        (
        select  b.actindx
        ,       sum(b.perdblnc) as total
        from    [CASH].[dbo].[GL10111] b
        group by
                b.actindx
        ) sub_b
on      b.actindx = act.actindx
where   act.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by 
        act.actindx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to join the result-sets of two (or more) queries:

In a more simplistic scenario:

```
SELECT 'Anna' as Name, 18 as Age
UNION 
SELECT 'Bob' as Name, 19 as Age
```

Result:

```
# | NAME  | AGE 
0 | Anna  | 18
1 | Bob   | 19
```

Comment: Eh, so how would you use a union to solve this particular problem?

Comment: @Andomar I was going to leave that as an exercise for the reader - I was looking more at the 'how do you combine two queries' part. But dotjoe shows one way. Of course, the solution you offer works equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like -
`select sum(a.perdblnc) + sum(c.perdblnc), a.actindx
from [CASH].[dbo].[GL00100] b
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10111] a
  inner join [CASH].[dbo].[GL10110] c
on b.actindx = a.actindx
where b.actnumbr_1 = 1020
group by a.actindx`